# Webpack dev-server - how to serve a static file with updated assets?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So my problem is that I can have webpack serve a directory listing when I go to `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/`. If I modify the dev server path, then it doesn't make any changes to the bundle.

I want a very simple setup. Take everything in app, perform js transforms and then serve it in dist. How does `index.html` fit it?

I have the following dir structure:

```
app
  index.js
dist
  bundle.js
index.html
webpack.config.js
```

And inside of webpack.config I have this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '.',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
    }
}
```

I interpret this as "start bundle at index.js, after transforming all js files using the babel-loader put that file called `bundle.js` into the `dist/`. Then on dev server, serve js content from that dist folder and compress."

The disconnect I have is in understanding how `index.html` plays into this. 
I have consulted: `https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver`.

I can change the `contentBase` path to be `.` and it will not show the directory listing but then it doesn't update the bundle.

**tldr:**

How can I enable the dev server to point to `index.html` but serve updated assets?

Finally, figured it out.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'dist',
    }
}
```

I'd love the say that I had an epiphany but I just spammed the options until it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If `contentBase` is `./dist`, then `index.html` is expected to exist in that directory. It's basically the directory where `webpack-dev-server` will look for static files (HTML, images, etc).

It doesn't necessarily have to be the same that you're using for the bundle; `output.path` is (AFAIK) not even used by `webpack-dev-server`, because it builds and serves the bundle from memory. The only thing required is `output.filename` and `output.publicPath` (although I believe the latter is also optional with Webpack v2, but then it will try and determine a public path itself), which are used to determine through with URL the bundle can be requested.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense now. Thanks! My new issue is that I can't get the dev server to update the bundle.

Comment: That's a bit weird, since I have a very similar setup for a project, and it's working just fine. Do you mean that the bundle file isn't being updated? Because like I said, `webpack-dev-server` builds and serves that file entirely from memory, it doesn't touch the actual bundle _file_ (for that, you'd run `webpack -w`).

Comment: If I change the code in `app/index.js` it does not demonstrate that result. If I add a alert, the page refreshes and no alert is called. If I run the webpack command without the dev server it works. It is only when using the dev server that it doesn't update.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but try providing a full (absolute) path to `entry`. When you change the file, there's nothing happening on the console of `webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: Hmm, but if entry works for webpack, wouldn't it also work for the dev-server?  I've literally gone to the https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver documentation and copied their configuration.  Sometimes, I miss gulp :(

Comment: Now my devServer option looks like: `publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),` It updates now on change. The update is still serving the old stuff though!

Comment: `publicPath` shouldn't be an absolute path, it's the prefix in the URL that `webpack-dev-server` will look for when requesting the bundle from it.